# SourceTree / BitBucket: Need Script to Add Many Versions of Project

Tags: bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree, bitbucket-api, bitbucket-server

I have a VBA project that has been religiously backed up daily for 12 months by exporting all modules to an otherwise empty folder; folder name corresponds to the backup date.

Recently I discovered SourceTree and BitBucket, so now I want to add all my backups to SourceTree (and probably BitBucket) to make it easier to see how the project has changed.

I need help to do this, basically I have a folder called backups and in that folder are ~360 folders that are named like: 2015-12-23, 2015-12-22, ..., 2015-01-01

Basically I'm stuck on how to get started with automating the addition of each set of files - figuring on using a script.  I can stage the files - just not sure how to load / upload / commit.

TIA

Comment: I would recommend scripting this using the git command line rather than the BitBucket API.  It will be simpler to script stage/commit to a local repository and then do a manual push to Bitbucket.

Comment: @BJMyers Thank you - I'm not sure how to even get started with that. Is git command line part of SourceTree? TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... going forward I'll be using [RubberDuckVBA](http://rubberduckvba.com) for this.